# Is it possible to bind a Spring controller request parameter to an object with multiple constructors?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, apache-commons-beanutils

I have `@RestController` with the following mapping:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/periods"})
public PeriodInfoDto get(DateRange dateRange)
```

DateRange has three constructors:

```
public class DateRange {

    @DateTimeFormat(iso=DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE)
    private YearMonth start;    

    @DateTimeFormat(iso=DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE)
    private YearMonth end;

    public DateRange(YearMonth start, YearMonth end) {
           this.start = start;
           this.end = end;
    }
            
    public DateRange(YearMonth end, Period period) {            
        this(end.minus(period.minusMonths(1)), end);
    }
```

When the client sends a request, the following exception is reported:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: No primary or single public
> constructor found for class
> com.example.domain.DateRange - and no default
> constructor found either  at
> org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.getResolvableConstructor(BeanUtils.java:250)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]

`DateRange` has a single primary constructor, `DateRange(YearMonth, YearMonth)`. The other constructor call this.

The client passes in a full date string such as 2021-01-01 for end / start date request params, but I only care about the month and year.

Is there a way to tell Spring to use `DateRange(YearMonth start, YearMonth end)` when binding the request?

Comment: The class has 2 constructors and spring cannot determine which one to use. What you can do is create a non `public` no-args constructor which Spring will use to construct the object. Or remove the other constructor using a `Period` and for instance replace that with a factory method. That way there would be a single constructor to use.

Comment: Also `2021-01-01` will not be converted/parsed to an `YearMonth` after the constructor issue gets solved as @M.Deinum mentioned. The input date string should be of the format `2021-01` for this code to work.

Comment: @M. Deinum - Thank you. That works well and solves my issue. In particular, I converted the `DateRange(YearMonth, Period)` constructor into a factory method. If you post your answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @R.G. - Thanks for your comment. You're correct. I changed my client to pass in for example `2021-01`. I was surprised that Spring was able to bind the String directly to a YearMonth instance without a  `String` to `YearMonth`  `Converter` or `@DateTimeFormat`. I saw other posts saying a `Converter` would be needed. I guess the version of Spring that I'm using, 2.4, has added support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stack trace indicates that Spring needs a so called primary constructor. For Java this means a single constructor that can be used. As you have 2 this mechanism fails.

You can work around this by removing the constructor using a `YearMonth` and `Period` and move that to a factory method and use that instead of the constructor.

```java
public class DateRange {

    private YearMonth start;    
    private YearMonth end;

    public DateRange(YearMonth start, YearMonth end) {
           this.start = start;
           this.end = end;
    }
            
    public static DateRange of(YearMonth end, Period period) {
        return new DateRange(end.minus(period.minusMonths(1)), end);            
    }
}
```

When using the format **2021-09** instead of a full date, Spring will automatically use the `YearMonthFormatter` (available since Spring 4.2) to convert from/to a `YearMonth`. So you don't need the `@DateTimeFormat` annotation that way.

Comment: Thanks for also adding the info about `YearMonthFormatter`. Much appreciated! Very helpful answer.